# Are There Adapters for CF Type II to MicroSD?

Tags: mobile, hardware, pocketpc

I honestly have only started recently researching this so my knowledge is limited. I was approached about adapting some Pocket PC software to operate on the Windows 6 platform. After considering how I would go about doing that in the Compact Framework I received more details.

It seems there is a desire to utilize (re-use) CF Type II devices on a mobile phone platform (using more modern miniSD or microSD slots).  While there exist plenty of microSD to CF adapters, there seems to be none going the other direction (even though I realize that would be an awkward looking adapter in physical design). **Is this true and what prevents this technically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that does this currently.  Likely because you can't exactly fit a CF card in a MicroSD card....it would have to have some weird cable coming off of it, which would likely cause it to no longer fit in the slot.  Also, CF is a Parallel interface while SD uses a Serial interface.